# Two ForEach loops, last one not iterating properly

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell

Essentially, i'm using `az` module to gather a list of keyvault IDs then dump those vaults. However, the second ForEach loop is only using the last entry in the variable that was obtained from the first ForEach loop.

```
If ($ListAllSecrets)
{
    $ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue"
    Write-Host "Gathering all keys from key vaults, this may take a moment"
    $vaults=az keyvault list --query '[].name' -o tsv
    ForEach ($vault in $vaults){
        $ids = az keyvault secret list --vault-name $vault --query '[].id' -o tsv
        $ids

        }
    ForEach ($i in $ids){
        $i
        az keyvault secret show --id $i | ConvertFrom-Json
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be like below.

```
If ($ListAllSecrets)
{
    $ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue"
    Write-Host "Gathering all keys from key vaults, this may take a moment"
    $vaults=az keyvault list --query '[].name' -o tsv
    ForEach ($vault in $vaults){
        $ids = az keyvault secret list --vault-name $vault --query '[].id' -o tsv
        $ids
             ForEach ($i in $ids){
                $i
                az keyvault secret show --id $i | ConvertFrom-Json
            }
        } 
}
```

Comment: Ahhh I see, I closed the first ForEach. Thanks